# Casting a number to a string by adding an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, casting

In JavaScript:

```
var stringVar = 12345 + []
```

Will cast the number to a string.

Small demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ce9bjcwo/

Why does this happen?

Comment: The rules for type conversion for the `+` operator are complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to `Array.prototype.toString()`.
It converts it to a string representation when trying to concatenate, and since 12345 is not a string, it's type-cast to one.

**Examples:**
`[1,2].toString()` -> `"1,2"`
`[].toString()` -> `""`
`12345 + ""` -> `"12345"`

Comment: Why downvote? Please leave comment so I can learn :)

Comment: I suppose people don't like this "feature" from Javascript. It's amazing to learn this, though. Thank you.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera I doubt people "not liking" how a language works will downvote an answer explaining it. Not that it _cannot_ happen, but I don't think it's really that likely. It's more likely that the dupe question has a way better answer than this one.

Comment: That's true. The answer in the dupe question is very thorough.

Comment: Indeed it is.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because:

There is no way to apply the + operator to an array, so Javascript stringifies the array.  Since it's an empty array, it stringifies as ''.  Then you have `12345 + ''`

And in javascirpt "number" + "string" returns a string, by casting the number to a string and treating + as concatenation operator.

Answer (score 1):

it's due to the fact it is trying to concatenate it to an empty string
You may understand it better if you try something like

```
  var stringVar = ""+123;
```

the amazing thing is that if you do

```
  stringVar = stringVar - 0 ;
```

it turns to an integer

then if you evaluate

`stringVar == '123'`

you get `true`

but if you evaluate

`stringVar === '123'`

you get `false`

so cool

Comment: It's not really _that_ amazing - the `+` operator is just doing too much stuff - maths AND concatenation, which forces it to have to decide on the fly which operation to apply and hence the type coercion. The `-` one is doing only mathematical operations, so it always returns a numeric type. But I'm not really sure that part of the answer really _answers_ the question.

Comment: @vlaz The `+` operator is actually doing just one thing, addition. It's just that there are two kinds of addition in programming: mathematical and string.

Comment: @ScottMarcus string concatenation is NOT addition. Some languages treat it as "the same" by overloading the `+` operator, however, PHP and Perl, for example, the concatenation operator is _different_ and is `.`, so you will have to know what you're doing: `"hello" . "world"` is the thing that will produce a new string. There are many other types of "addition" in programming that _could_ be handled by `+` but aren't because it will lead to weird overload cases.

Comment: @vlaz Actually string concatenation IS addition. It's string addition which results in concatenation. This concept is the same in all languages however, some languages allow the developer to explicitly choose which variant they want with a dedicated operator. JavaScript does not - it uses an overload instead.

Comment: @ScottMarcus—the `+` punctuator is interpreted as one of two operators. The  [*addition operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus) which results in either mathematic addition (returning a Number) or string concatenation (returning in a String). String concatenation is a distinctly different operation from numeric addition. `+` can also be interpreted as the [*unary + operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator) which does type conversion to Number as for *ToNumber*, so it performs 3 different operations.